# What is the preferred way to add many fields to all documents in a MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, python-3.4

I have have a Python application that is iteratively going through every document in a MongoDB (3.0.2) collection (typically between 10K and 1M documents), and adding new fields (probably doubling/tripling the number of fields in the document).

My initial thought was that I would use upsert the entire of the revised documents (using pyMongo) - now I'm questioning that:

- Given that the revised documents are significantly bigger should I be inserting only the new fields, or just replacing the document?
- Also, is it better to perform a write to the collection on a document by document basis or in bulk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is actually a great question that can be solved a few different ways depending on how you are managing your data.

if you are upserting additional fields does this mean your data is appending additional fields at a later point in time with the only changes being the addition of the additional fields?  if so you could **[set the ttl on your documents so that the old ones drop off over time](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)**.  keep in mind that if you do this you will want to set an index that sorts your results by descending _id so that the most recent additions are selected before the older ones.

the benefit of this of doing it this way is that your are continually writing data as opposed to seeking and updating data so it is faster.

in regards to upserts vs bulk inserts.  bulk inserts are always faster than upserts since bulk upserting [requires you to find the original document first](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/bulk.html).

- Given that the revised documents are significantly bigger should I be inserting only the new fields, or just replacing the document?

  - you really need to understand your data fully to determine what is best but if only change to the data is additional fields or changes that only need to be considered from that point forward then bulk inserting and setting a ttl on your older data is the better method from the stand point of write operations as opposed to seek, find and update. when using this method you will want to `db.document.find_one()` as opposed to `db.document.find()` so that only your current record is returned.
- Also, is it better to perform a write to the collection on a document by document basis or in bulk?

  - bulk inserts will be faster than inserting each one sequentially.